# Where can I find a reliable archive of Hitler's speeches?

Tags: world-war-two, resource, historical-research

Working on [the answer for this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/26369/4615), I wanted a copy of Hitler's speech from March 16, 1935 which is so often referenced in German rearmament.  [I found a translation](http://der-fuehrer.org/reden/english/35-03-16.htm), but it's on [der-fuehrer.org](http://der-fuehrer.org/) which is some Neo-Nazi web site.  Not only don't I trust their academic rigor, I don't want to send anyone to their site.  Other, more reliable, archives did not have this speech.

This problem comes up a lot.

Where can I find reliable archives of Hitler's speeches and proclamations?  Preferably original German with English translations, but even just German will do.

Comment: @TylerDurden Might you consider removing that comment, please?

Comment: John Toland writes in *Chapter 14* (*With the Assurance of a Sleepwalker*) of **Adolf Hitler I**, "He later boasted to his inner circle "... I threatened, unless the situation eased within twenty four hours, to send in 6 extra divisions; in fact I had only 4 brigades.'"

Comment: I would recommend to check a library for this. The collection of Hitler's speeches by Max Domarus has even its own Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitler:_Speeches_and_Proclamations

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for sources/references.

Answer (score 3):

I grabbed a couple sentences of the linked speech, tossed quotes around it and dropped it into a Google search.  It spit back a link to [Full text of "Adolf Hitler Collection Of Speeches 1922 1945"](https://archive.org/stream/AdolfHitlerCollectionOfSpeeches19221945/Adolf%20Hitler%20-%20Collection%20of%20Speeches%201922-1945_djvu.txt) on archive.org.  Unfortunately it doesn't have the original German text, but it seems to be a quite comprehensive collection.

I'm guessing that if you have some of the untranslated German texts, you can use a similar method to find to locate them on a more academically palatable site.

Comment: Thanks. I found a lot of his speeches on archive.org, including audio, but didn't find that list. [I found the original that archive.org scanned](http://nseuropa.org/English/Adolf%20Hitler%20-%20Collection%20of%20Speeches%20-%201922-1945.pdf) and unfortunately it contains no sources or translation notes. [The originating site is, alas, some neo-Nazi thing](http://nseuropa.org/news-en.htm).

Comment: @Schwern: For this speech, and perhaps many others of his pre-war speeches, Hitler himself was so good at the Big Lie that I am not sure these neo-Nazi groups can, or even have to, twist the wording at all. In fact, any attempt to do so might do more harm than good to their intent.

Comment: @Schwern - Unfortunately, history has a way of favoring the victors even in what source material gets retained.  The political and social climate in post-war Germany wasn't particularly conducive to preserving materials like these for exactly the same reason you hesitate to post a link to a neo-Nazi site.  I suppose an argument could be made that as repugnant as they are, neo-Nazi groups have actually played a pretty important role in making sure this type of source material is available at all.

Comment: Notice that the very file linked above is a highly dubious, convoluted _and_ unreliable collection that states on its last page to have been assembled by a neo-nazi website and is signed-off to have been collected by "Made by Propagandaleiter" (that is: someone seeing himself as epigone of Joseph Goebbels? In clear words: it's garbage, and nowhere near trustworthiness.